Is it possible to make a table which has different rows for each column via gird box?

Can I use grid-box to achieve the layout of this table?
I know that if the rows for each column is a times to each other, it will be possible.
I am not sure if I can use grid-box to make a table which has different number of rows in each column and the number are not times of each other.

It's only possible if you know how many child elements are in each column

It is also possible by adding different divs for left elements and right elements. It can also work with dynamic data but you have structure your html properly as per your need.

I'm not sure I completely understand the requirement. Your image seems to show a simple grid with 6 rows, the items in the first column having 2 rows each and the second column having 3 rows each. However, your verbal description indicates that the height of the items in the second row is not connected to (you use the word 'times') the height of the items in the first row. Which is the requirement?

There are multiple ways to achieve the desired layout using CSS Grid. The trick is to have the grid items in the first column to span multiple rows to allow the grid items in the second and third columns to be aligned in the middle of the grid item that is placed at second row, first column.
The following example uses grid-template-areas to achieve the desired output:


.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  height: 300px;
  grid-gap: 3px;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas: 
    "sm1 wd1 wd2" 
    "sm1 wd1 wd2" 
    "sm2 wd1 wd2" 
    "sm2 wd3 wd4" 
    "sm3 wd3 wd4" 
    "sm3 wd3 wd4";
}

.grid-item {
  background: #999;
}

.grid-item:nth-of-type(1) { grid-area: sm1; }
.grid-item:nth-of-type(2) { grid-area: wd1; }
.grid-item:nth-of-type(3) { grid-area: wd2; }
.grid-item:nth-of-type(4) { grid-area: sm2; }
.grid-item:nth-of-type(5) { grid-area: wd3; }
.grid-item:nth-of-type(6) { grid-area: wd4; }
.grid-item:nth-of-type(7) { grid-area: sm3; }
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
</div>




Your solution is really an ingenious one. 2*3=6, then divide the table into six rows, haha
